# Covering induces integral homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, commutative-algebra

Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ and define $f:S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ by $f(z)=z^n$. Let $A$ be a ring of continuous functions from $S^1$ to $\mathbb{R}.$ Let $\psi:A \rightarrow A$ by $\psi(\phi)=\phi \circ f.$ Prove that $\psi$ is integral extension, that is, $A$ is integral over $\psi(A)$.

I think we have to use of compactness of $S^1$ and that $f(z)=z^n$, but I have a problems to make it rigorous...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: First show that for any $z\in S^1$ and any $a\in A$, you can find $b\in \psi(A)$ such that $a(w)-b(w)=0$ for all $w$ in a neighborhood of $z$.  Then, think about how you can combine these to find an integral equation $a$ satisfies on all of $S^1$.

A full proof is hidden below:

> The image $\psi(A)$ consists of the functions that are (multiplicatively) $e^{2\pi i/n}$-periodic.  Given any interval $I$ on $S^1$ of length less than $e^{2\pi i/n}$, you can extend a continuous function on $I$ to an $e^{2\pi i/n}$-periodic function on all of $S^1$.  In particular, this means that for any $a\in A$, you can find $b\in \psi(A)$ such that $a(w)=b(w)$ for all $w\in I$.  Now we can cover $S^1$ by finitely many such intervals $I_1,\dots,I_m$ and find $b_1,\dots,b_m$ such that $a_k(w)=b_k(w)$ if $w\in I_k$.  Then $(a-b_1)(a-b_2)\dots(a-b_m)$ vanishes on all of $S^1$, and is a monic polynomial in $a$ with coefficients in $\psi(A)$.